# Flutter - How to get current route?

Tags: flutter, dart

I recevice a remote notification, and it will call the method below.
In this method, I will judge which current route it is, And excute diffrent method.

```
   jPush.addEventHandler(
        onReceiveNotification: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {

      // How to get current display route here?
   });
```

How to get current display route here? There is no context here.
In main.dart, I define a navigatorKey.

```
MaterialApp(
        title: '',
        navigatorKey: MyRouters.navigatoeKey,
        ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you can not get the current route without the app `context`.
I can suggest a workaround here, save the current route in state management. When notification arrives, just check the state value to get the current route.

Comment: Do you mean using navigatorObserver?

Comment: @zhouxinle yes, according to my understanding to your question, that will do your job.

Comment: jPush.addEventHandler() in this method, How to judge a dialog show on the screen and pop? is also using a Array to store route and judge?